# How to remove polyline straight line and just retain driving line?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, polyline

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var markers = [
            {
                "title": 'Shah Alam',
            "lat": '3.068621',
            "lng": '101.518342',

        }
    ,
        {
            "title": 'Ipoh',
            "lat": '4.600050',
            "lng": '101.075641',

        }
    ,
        {
            "title": 'Putrajaya',
            "lat": '2.908764',
            "lng": '101.675053',
        }
    ,
        {
            "title": 'Seremban',
            "lat": '2.726553',
            "lng": '101.934491',
        }
    ,
        {
            "title": 'Ampang',
            "lat": '3.151621',
            "lng": '101.767996',
        }
];
    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var lat_lng = new Array();
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
        map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

        //***********ROUTING****************//

        //Intialize the Path Array
        var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

        //Intialize the Direction Service
        var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        //Set the Path Stroke Color
        var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#4986E7' });

        //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
        for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
            if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) 
            {
                var src = lat_lng[i];
                var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
                path.push(src);
                poly.setPath(path);
                service.route(
                {
                    origin: src,
                    destination: des,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                }, function (result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I tested the code which actually produce two set of line(one straight lines and one driving mode line). I would like to remove the straight line and retain only driving mode line. How can i achieved that? As i comment out some line, it will only retain the straight line but never successful in retaining driving mode line.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two things incorrectly.

1. You are pushing the src onto the path, when you don't need to
2. You are combining the lines into a single polyline.  The directions service is asynchronous, so the lines may not be returned in the order you expect.

Simplest fix is to create a separate polyline for each directions result.

```
//Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
  if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
    var src = lat_lng[i];
    var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
    service.route({
      origin: src,
      destination: des,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function(result, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        //Set the Path Stroke Color
        var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
          map: map,
          strokeColor: '#4986E7'
        });
        //Intialize the Path Array
        var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
        for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
          path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
        }
        poly.setPath(path);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/7g5x5jed/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```js
var markers = [{
  "title": 'Shah Alam',
  "lat": '3.068621',
  "lng": '101.518342',

}, {
  "title": 'Ipoh',
  "lat": '4.600050',
  "lng": '101.075641',

}, {
  "title": 'Putrajaya',
  "lat": '2.908764',
  "lng": '101.675053',
}, {
  "title": 'Seremban',
  "lat": '2.726553',
  "lng": '101.934491',
}, {
  "title": 'Ampang',
  "lat": '3.151621',
  "lng": '101.767996',
}];
window.onload = function() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var lat_lng = new Array();
  var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i]
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: data.title
    });
    latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
    (function(marker, data) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    })(marker, data);
  }
  map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
  map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

  //***********ROUTING****************//

  //Intialize the Direction Service
  var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  // Create a new polyline, set the Path Stroke Color
  var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    strokeColor: '#4986E7'
  });

  //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
  for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
    if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
      var src = lat_lng[i];
      var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
      service.route({
        origin: src,
        destination: des,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      }, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          //Set the Path Stroke Color
          var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
            map: map,
            strokeColor: '#4986E7'
          });
          //Intialize the Path Array
          var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
          for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
          }
          poly.setPath(path);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#dvMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="dvMap"></div>
```

Comment: ... and delete `if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length)` and add in "for" above  `i < lat_lng.length - 1`

Answer (score 0):

And variant with `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;`

https://jsfiddle.net/7b4yj2ug/

EASY version:

```js
var markers = [{
  "title": 'Shah Alam',
  "lat": '3.068621',
  "lng": '101.518342',
}, {
  "title": 'Ipoh',
  "lat": '4.600050',
  "lng": '101.075641',
}, {
  "title": 'Putrajaya',
  "lat": '2.908764',
  "lng": '101.675053',
}, {
  "title": 'Seremban',
  "lat": '2.726553',
  "lng": '101.934491',
}, {
  "title": 'Ampang',
  "lat": '3.151621',
  "lng": '101.767996',
}];

window.onload = function() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
  
  var waypts = [];
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i]
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
     waypts.push({       
      location: myLatlng,
     });
  }
  //***********ROUTING****************//

  //Intialize the Direction Service
  var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
 
  //Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
 
  service.route({
    origin: waypts[0],
    destination: waypts[waypts.length - 1],
    waypoints: waypts.slice(1, waypts.length - 1),
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#dvMap,
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <div id="dvMap"></div>
```

**Attention!**  [*maximum allowed waypoints is 8 (API 3.26)*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest)

> **waypoints**
>   Type:  Array
>   
>   Array of intermediate waypoints. Directions will be calculated from the origin to the destination by way of each waypoint in this array. The maximum allowed waypoints is 8, plus the origin, and destination. Premium Plan customers are allowed 23 waypoints, plus the origin, and destination. Waypoints are not supported for transit directions. Optional.